# How to use GET method on checkbox in Python 2.7

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to use the .GET form method on a check box, select tag and radio button in Python2.7 utilising google app engine and thats it. 
here is the code so far

HTML

```
<form method='GET'>
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="checkbox">
<select name='select'>
</form>
```

Python Code

```
select = self.request.GET['select']
checkbox = self.request.GET['name']
```

This works for my standard input fields (such as text) but not on any other type of input I use. I have looked everywhere for the documentation on this but have come up empty, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So much information missing from this question. What framework are you using? How are you submitting the form? What do you see when you try this?

Comment: Did you try working with Selenium?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard input fields" and what are the other types of input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a checkbox is *not* checked, the browser doesn't send the field.

`GET` is a [`MultiDict` object](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/modules/webob.html#webob.multidict.MultiDict), which acts just like a dictionary. As such you can use containment testing with `in` to see if the checkbox is present in the request:

```
checkbox = 'name' in self.request.GET
```

This sets a boolean `True` or `False`.

Alternatively, test for it instead with the `.get()` method:

```
checkbox = bool(self.request.GET.get('name'))
```

`GET.get('name')` returns `None` (a false value) if the checkbox is missing from the request, otherwise it'll return `'checkbox'` (a true value).

For `<select>` elements, if none of the options are selected, it too is omitted from the request. If there is a default value you'd pick, then you can do so with:

```
select = self.request.GET.get('select', 'default value')
```

For the precise rules as to what a browser will include in the form, see the [Successful controls specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2); only controls that are successful are included.

Comment: `'name' in self.request.GET` looks more pythonic to me.

Comment: @bereal: the Webapp2 link to the [`MultiDict` class documentation](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/modules/webob.html#webob.multidict.MultiDict) was broken; I wanted to confirm first that containment would work. The docs are vague on the subject, only *the normal dictionary interface* is claimed to be implemented, so I needed to check the source.

Comment: The Second worked, do you have any advice for the select tag?

Comment: @user3848142: the same applies to `<select>`; it is not posted if there is no selected `<option>`.

Comment: When I use that syntax it gives me an invalid error.

Comment: @user3848142: then you made a different mistake, perhaps on the line before it.

Comment: I need it to actually print the value of a multi select option.

Comment: @user3848142: for a multiselect, where more than one option is possible, use `self.request.GET.getlist('select')`; it'll return a list, always, which *can* be empty.